# SGTIN96 encode for EPC on RFID

Tags: java

This is a class to encode and decode SGTIN96 product identifiers, typically used to write EPC on RFID tags. Refer to [EPC(TM) Generation 1 Tag Data Standards Version 1.1 Rev.1.27](http://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/tds_1_1_rev_1_27-standard-20050510.pdf).

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// Refer to EPCTM Generation 1 Tag Data Standards Version 1.1 Rev.1.27
// http://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/tds_1_1_rev_1_27-standard-20050510.pdf

public class SGTIN96 {
    // Table 6. The EPC SGTIN-96 bit allocation, header, and maximum decimal values. page 27.
    private final static Integer BIN = 2;
    private final static Integer HEX = 16;
    private final static String sgtin96_bin_header = "00110000";
    private final static Integer sgtin96_filter_value_bits = 3;
    private final static Integer sgtin96_partition_value_bits = 3;
    private final static Integer sgtin96_serial_number_bits = 38;
    private final static Integer sgtin96_length_bits = 96;
    private final static Integer sgtin96_length_hex = 24;
    private static HashMap<Integer, int[]> sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions;

    static {
        // Table 7. SGTIN-96 Partitions. page 28.
        // Column order: (L), P, M, N Nd
        sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
        sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.put(12, new int[]{0, 40, 4, 1});
        sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.put(11, new int[]{1, 37, 7, 2});
        sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.put(10, new int[]{2, 34, 10, 3});
        sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.put(9, new int[]{3, 30, 14, 4});
        sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.put(8, new int[]{4, 27, 17, 5});
        sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.put(7, new int[]{5, 24, 20, 6});
        sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.put(6, new int[]{6, 20, 24, 7});
    }

    private static int[] getPartitionsByCompanyPrefixLengthInDigits(int company_prefix_length) {
        // column 3 (L)
        return sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.get(company_prefix_length);
    }

    private static int[] getPartitionsByPartitionValue(int partition_value) {
        // column 1 (P)
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, int[]> parts : sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions.entrySet()) {
            // System.out.println("Key = " + parts.getKey() + ", Value = " + parts.getValue());
            if (parts.getValue()[0] == partition_value) {
                int[]rv = parts.getValue();
                rv[0] = parts.getKey();
                return rv;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid partition value");
    }

    private static String longToBinaryWithFill(Long number, int bits) {
        // This is never called with any number larger than 40 bits, so Long is a good choice
        return zeroFill(Long.toBinaryString(number), bits);
    }

    private static String zeroFill(String s, int n) {
        int fill = n - s.length();
        String Zeroes = "";
        if (fill > 0) {
            Zeroes = new String(new char[fill]).replace("\0", "0");
        }
        return Zeroes + s;
    }

    private static String binaryToHex(String bin) {
        // bin_epc is 96 bits, so need to use BitInt for hex conversion
        return new BigInteger(bin, BIN).toString(HEX);
    }

    private static String hexToBinary(String hex) {
        return new BigInteger(hex, HEX).toString(BIN);
    }

    private static Long binaryToLong(String bin) {
        return Long.parseLong(bin, BIN);
    }

    private static Integer binaryToInt(String bin) {
        return Integer.parseInt(bin, BIN);
    }


    public static String encodeUPC(String upc, Long serial_number) {
        if (upc.length() != 12) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("UPC must be 12 digits long");
        }
        // UPC-12 barcodes in this use case have 6 digit company identifier
        // Table 5. SGTIN Filter Values. page 24.
        return encode(zeroFill(upc, 14), 6, serial_number, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Encodes an SGTIN-96 encoded EPC ID.
     *
     * Follows the procedures details in document "EPC Generation 1 Tag Data
     * Standards Version 1.1 Rev.1.27" which can be found at:
     * http://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/tds_1_1_rev_1_27-standard-20050510.pdf
     *
     * @param  gtin14 - the 14 character GTIN
     * @param  company_prefix_length - The length L of the Company Prefix portion of the GTIN
     * @param  serial_number - A Serial Number S where 0 ≤ S < 238, or an UCC/EAN-128 Application Identifier 21
     * @param  filter_value - A Filter Value F where 0 ≤ F < 8
     * @return       a 24 character EPC
     */
    public static String encode(String gtin14, Integer company_prefix_length, Long serial_number, Integer filter_value) {
        // 3.4.2.1 SGTIN-96 Encoding Procedure. page 28.
        if (serial_number.toString().length() > 1 && serial_number.toString().charAt(0) == '0') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("serial number may not begin with 0");
        }
        int[] partitions = getPartitionsByCompanyPrefixLengthInDigits(company_prefix_length);
        if (partitions == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("company prefix length must be <=12 and >= 6");
        }
        Integer partition_value = partitions[0];
        Integer company_prefix_bits = partitions[1];
        Integer item_reference_and_indicator_bits = partitions[2];

        if (gtin14.length() != 14) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("GTIN must be 14 digits long");
        }

        Long company_prefix = Long.valueOf(gtin14.substring(1, (company_prefix_length + 1)));
        Long item_reference_and_indicator = Long.valueOf(gtin14.charAt(0) +
                gtin14.substring(company_prefix_length + 1, 13));

        String bin_filter_value = longToBinaryWithFill((long) filter_value, sgtin96_filter_value_bits);
        String bin_partition_value = longToBinaryWithFill((long) partition_value, sgtin96_partition_value_bits);
        String bin_company_prefix = longToBinaryWithFill(company_prefix, company_prefix_bits);
        String bin_item_reference = longToBinaryWithFill(item_reference_and_indicator, item_reference_and_indicator_bits);
        String bin_serial_number = longToBinaryWithFill(serial_number, sgtin96_serial_number_bits);

        String bin_epc = sgtin96_bin_header + bin_filter_value + bin_partition_value + bin_company_prefix + bin_item_reference + bin_serial_number;

        return zeroFill(binaryToHex(bin_epc), sgtin96_length_hex);
    }

    /**
     * Decodes an SGTIN-96 encoded EPC ID.
     *
     * Follows the procedures details in document "EPC Generation 1 Tag Data;
     * Standards Version 1.1 Rev.1.27" which can be found at;
     * http://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/tds_1_1_rev_1_27-standard-20050510.pdf
     *
     * @param  sgtin96_epc - the SGTIN-96 encoded EPC ID
     * @return       HashMap<String, String> with the keys:
     * filter_value - Encoded Filter Value
     * item_reference - Item Reference
     * serial_number - Serial Number
     * gtin14 - Encoded GTIN-14
     */
    public static HashMap<String, String> decode(String sgtin96_epc) {
        // 3.4.2.2 SGTIN-96 Decoding Procedure. page 29.
        if (sgtin96_epc.length() != sgtin96_length_hex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("EPC must be 24 characters long");
        }
        String binary = zeroFill(hexToBinary(sgtin96_epc), sgtin96_length_bits);

        String header = binary.substring(0, 8);
        if (!header.equals(sgtin96_bin_header)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("EPC header does not correlate to SGTIN-96");
        }

        Integer filter_value = binaryToInt(binary.substring(8, 11));
        Integer partition_value = binaryToInt(binary.substring(11, 14));
        if (partition_value > 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Partition value cannot be greater than 6");
        }

        int[] lookup = getPartitionsByPartitionValue(partition_value);

        Integer company_prefix_len_bits = lookup[1];
        Integer company_prefix_len_digits = lookup[0];

        Long long_company_prefix_value = binaryToLong(binary.substring(14, 14 + company_prefix_len_bits));
        if (long_company_prefix_value >= Math.pow(10, company_prefix_len_digits)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Company Prefix exceeded specified length");
        }
        String company_prefix = zeroFill(long_company_prefix_value.toString(), company_prefix_len_digits);

        Integer item_reference_and_indicator_len_digits = 13 - company_prefix_len_digits;
        Integer int_item_reference_and_indicator = binaryToInt(binary.substring(14 + company_prefix_len_bits, 58));
        if (int_item_reference_and_indicator >= Math.pow(10, item_reference_and_indicator_len_digits) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item Reference and Indicator exceeded specified length");
        }
        String item_reference_and_indicator = zeroFill(int_item_reference_and_indicator.toString(), item_reference_and_indicator_len_digits);

        String thirteen = item_reference_and_indicator.substring(0, 1) + company_prefix + item_reference_and_indicator.substring(1);
        int termA = 0;
        int termB = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < thirteen.length(); i++){
            String c = thirteen.substring(i, i+1);
            if (i%2 == 0) {
                termB += Integer.parseInt(c);
            } else {
                termA += Integer.parseInt(c);
            }
        }
        int check_digit = Math.abs(((-3 * termA) - termB) % 10);
        String gtin14 = thirteen + String.valueOf(check_digit);

        Long serial_number = binaryToLong(binary.substring(58));

        HashMap<String, String> rv = new HashMap<String, String>();
        rv.put("filter_value", filter_value.toString());
        rv.put("item_reference", item_reference_and_indicator);
        rv.put("serial_number", serial_number.toString());
        rv.put("gtin14", gtin14);

        return rv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Use `Map` instead of `HashMap` for variable/return type declaration**

   ```
   private static HashMap<Integer, int[]> sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions;

   public static HashMap<String, String> decode(String sgtin96_epc) {
       // ...
       HashMap<String, String> rv = new HashMap<String, String>();
       // ...
       return rv;
   }
   ```

   These can be declared as `Map` instead of `HashMap`, as all the users/callers of the variable and method only need to operate on the `Map` interface, instead of knowing that it's a `HashMap` implementation.
2. **Naming convention**

   Interestingly, only `BIN` and `HEX` are provided using Java's naming convention for `static final` (small note here, but I think `static final` is more often used...) fields, and the rest are not. I'm not sure if there's a peculiar coding style you are adhering to here, but further standardization may be desired. :)

   Java's naming convention is also `camelCase` for fields, rather than `snake_case` as you have used here, but at least you are using this style consistently...
3. **Zero-padding**

   Instead of always prepending a `zeroes` (note: small `z`) to the input `String` even when it is long enough, you may want to simplify the step here as such:

   ```
   private static String zeroFill(String s, int n) {
       return s.length() >= n ? s
               : new String(new char[n - s.length()]).replace('\0', '0') + s;
   }
   ```

   Note that [`replace(char, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) is also used here, as it will likely offer better performance over the `CharSequence`/`Pattern`-based implementation.
4. **Auto-boxing**

   There are a few places where the use of the `Integer` wrapper class can simply be done with the primitive `int` equivalent. Again, some form of consistency here will be preferred, partly to aid in readability, and partly also to eliminate any possible chances of `NullPointerException` when you (accidentally?) create `null` instances of `Integer`.
5. **Better modeling class...?**

   Given the various places where you are accessing the array elements, I wonder if using better modeling classes may be of some help here to improve the readability and to standardize the usage of the array elements. For example (reducing empty lines here solely to make it fit into the box without the scrollbars):

   ```
   enum Partition {
       SIX(20, 24), SEVEN(24, 20), EIGHT(27, 17), NINE(30, 14), 
       TEN(34, 10), ELEVEN(37, 7), TWELVE(40, 4);

       private final int companyPrefixBits;
       private final int itemReferenceIndicatorBits;
       private Partition(int companyPrefixBits, int itemReferenceIndicatorBits) {
           this.companyPrefixBits = companyPrefixBits;
           this.itemReferenceIndicatorBits = itemReferenceIndicatorBits;
       }
       public int getCompanyPrefixLength() {
           return ordinal() + 6;
       }            
       public int getPartitionValue() {
           return ordinal();
       }
       public int getCompanyPrefixBits() {
           return companyPrefixBits;
       }
       public int getItemReferenceIndicatorBits() {
           return itemReferenceIndicatorBits;
       }
       public static Partition getByCompanyPrefixLength(int companyPrefixLength) {
           if (companyPrefixLength < 6 || companyPrefixLength > 12) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid company prefix length."); 
               // or return null?
           }
           return values()[companyPrefixLength - 6];
       }
       public static Partition getByPartitionValue(int partitionValue) {
           if (partitionValue < 0 || partitionValue > 6) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid partition value.");
           }
           return values()[6 - partitionValue];
       }            
   }
   ```

   With this, you eliminate the reliance on accessing the array elements, and you get the bonus of calling the values as they are 'known', e.g. `Partition.getCompanyPrefixLength()` instead of `partitionValues[0]`. The two `public static` methods above simply replaces the current `getPartitionsByCompanyPrefixLengthInDigits(int)` and `getPartitionsByPartitionValue(int)` methods.

Answer (score 3):

I hope there are tests.  Because when I attempted to refactor some parts
I wasn't quite sure if it retained the meaning or not.

There are docstrings, but I think the exceptional situations should at
least be mentioned, i.e. "Malformed input will raise an exception
instead of returning empty output." or so.

Reuse computed values, e.g. `serial_number.toString()`, to reduce the
lines of code to read; it will be probably optimised away regardless.

Some variables don't have the best names, e.g. `thirteen` doesn't tell
anything about the intended use.

`sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions` can be `final` too.

The inner part of the loop could reuse the same computation.  Also
`substring` isn't the best option here - `charAt` is potentially more
performant, but also requires changing `parseInt` to something
different; see also
[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char):

```
int parsed = Character.getNumericValue(thirteen.charAt(i));
if (i%2 == 0) {
    termB += parsed;
} else {
    termA += parsed;
}
```

The return value should be more structured than a map, the easiest way
for that would be a value class with three members:

```
public static class EPCID {
    /**
     * Encoded Filter Value
     */
    private final String filterValue;
    /**
     * Item Reference
     */
    private final String itemReference;
    /**
     * Serial Number
     */
    private final String serialNumber;
    /**
     * Encoded GTIN-14
     */
    private final String gtin14;

    public EPCID(String filterValue, String itemReference, String serialNumber, String gtin14) {
        this.filter_value = filterValue;
        this.item_reference = itemReference;
        this.serial_number = serialNumber;
        this.gtin14 = gtin14;
    }

    public String getFilterValue() {
        return this.filterValue;
    }

    public String getItemReference() {
        return this.itemReference;
    }

    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return this.serialNumber;
    }

    public String getGtin14() {
        return this.gtin14;
    }
}
```

Which is then returned from the method:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @return the decoded EPCID
 */
public static EPCID decode(String sgtin96_epc) {
    ...
    return new EPCID(filter_value.toString(), item_reference_and_indicator, serial_number.toString(), gtin14);
}
```

Possibly change the data types if `String` isn't actually the best
option there.  If the map is really needed I'd add a conversion/view to
the value class instead.

The helper functions (binary to hex and back) should probably be moved
into a separate class if used anywhere else since they aren't really
part of this classes responsibility.

The zero-fill function can be a bit nicer by exiting early and using
[`Arrays.fill`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128737/fastest-way-to-set-all-values-of-an-array)
instead of the `replace` call, which does more than you need it to:

```
private static String zeroFill(String s, int n) {
    int fill = n - s.length();
    if (fill == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    char[] zeroes = new char[fill];
    Arrays.fill(zeroes, '0');
    return zeroes + s;
}
```

If it's a concern the whole class should be profiled for unnecessary
allocations btw. since it's using a lot of string contenations
etc. which could possibly be avoided by using
[`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html),
or by preallocating space.

That `serial_number` is sometimes a `Long` and sometimes a `String` is
hopefull not an issue?  E.g. a leading zero doesn't have to be
preserved?

The serial number check can be moved out of the `encode` method easily:

```
private static void checkSerialNumber(Long serial_number) {
    String serial_number_string = serial_number.toString();
    if (serial_number_string.length() > 1 && serial_number_string.charAt(0) == '0') {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("serial number may not begin with 0");
    }
}
```

This also highlights one question:  In which situation, except it being
`0`, does this raise an exception?

Unless I'm missing something, `sgtin96_company_prefix_len_partitions`
could very well be a regular two-dimensional array instead of a map.

The naming scheme is all over the place; at least constants should be
uppercase though, that makes it a bit easier to understand.

Some common code can still be factored out,
e.g. `binaryToInt(string.substring(...))` can be moved into a separate
method as it's used quite often:

```
private static Integer binarySubstringToInt(String bin, int start, int end) {
    return Integer.parseInt(bin.substring(start, end), BIN);
}
```

The method `getPartitionsByPartitionValue` returns an opaque `int[]`
array.  It would be better if the return value actually had some
meaningful name.  The method is also linearly scanning the list, which
is per se bad; since the input value is already verified, I'd rather
have a pre-constructed array somewhere, where it would be just
`array[partition_value]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For any other persons interested on RFID Encoding/Decoding in Java/Android.
This library seems to be interesting: https://github.com/jlcout/epctagcoder

This library is based on [EPC Tag Data Standard 1.9](https://www.gs1.org/standards/epcrfid-epcis-id-keys/epc-rfid-tds/1-13). It contains all the possible EPC encodings (including SGTIN-96 and SGTIN-198):

**Epc implementations**:

SGTIN - Serialized Global Trade Item Number

SSCC - Serial Shipping Container Code

SGLN - Global Location Number With or Without Extension

GRAI - Global Returnable Asset Identifier

GIAI - Global Individual Asset Identifier

GSRN - Global Service Relation Number – Recipient

GSRNP - Global Service Relation Number – Provider

GDTI - Global Document Type Identifier

CPI - Component / Part Identifier

SGCN - Serialized Global Coupon Number

**Examples** (Here it's SSCC but with SGTIN-96 it's the same logic):

```
ParseSSCC parseSSCC = ParseSSCC.Builder()
    .withCompanyPrefix("023356789")
    .withExtensionDigit( SSCCExtensionDigit.EXTENSION_3 )
    .withSerial("0200002")
    .withTagSize( SSCCTagSize.BITS_96 )
    .withFilterValue( SSCCFilterValue.RESERVED_5 )
    .build();
SSCC sscc = parseSSCC.getSSCC();
System.out.println("parseSSCC  "+ sscc.toString() );


ParseSSCC parseSSCC = ParseSSCC.Builder()
       .withRFIDTag( "31AC16465751CCD0C2000000" )
       .build();
SSCC sscc = parseSSCC.getSSCC();
System.out.println("parseSSCC  "+ sscc.toString() );


ParseSSCC parseSSCC = ParseSSCC.Builder()
       .withEPCTagURI( "urn:epc:tag:sscc-96:5.023356789.30200002" )
       .build();
SSCC sscc = parseSSCC.getSSCC();
System.out.println("parseSSCC  "+ sscc.toString() );


ParseSSCC parseSSCC = ParseSSCC.Builder()
       .withEPCPureIdentityURI( "urn:epc:id:sscc:023356789.30200002" )
       .withTagSize( SSCCTagSize.BITS_96 )
       .withFilterValue( SSCCFilterValue.RESERVED_5 )
       .build();
SSCC sscc = parseSSCC.getSSCC();
System.out.println("parseSSCC  "+ sscc.toString() );
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. The answers to the questions should contain meaningful observations about the code as well as suggestions for improvements. Could you point out why the library should be used instead of the posters code.

Comment: This library is based on EPC Tag Data Standard 1.9 and adds additionnal EPC encodings. The previous codes only covers SGTIN-96, while the library covers SGTIN (96 AND 198), SSCC, SGLN, GRAI, GIAI, GSRN, GSRNP, GDTI, CPI, SGCN

Comment: I meant it should have been added to the answer. I'm not the person that voted down.